# CSS multiple classes property override

Tags: css

If I have a style class defined as such:

```
.myclass{
    //bunch of other stuff
    float:left;
}
```

and I define another class like this:

```
.myclass-right{
    float:right;
}
```

and I define a div this way:

```
<div class="myclass myclass-right"></div>
```

Will that div inherit everything from myclass, but override the float property to float:right? That's what I'd expect to happen. Also kind of want to know if that has any cross-browser implications (good browsers vs. IE 7 or greater, f*** IE6).

Comment: Yes that's the way it'll work, and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/Fr8Te/) is a jsfiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066356/multiple-css-classes-properties-overlapping-based-on-the-order-defined

Comment: Oops. It is a dupe. Guess I didn't look hard enough. Give me 5 minutes before you close it down so I can give one lucky contestant another 15 rep for their helpful answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As long as the selectors have the same specificity (in this case they do) and `.myclass-right` style block is defined after `.myclass`, yes.

Edit to expand: the order the classes appear in the html element has no effect, the only thing that matters is the specificity of the selector and the order in which the selectors appear in the style sheet.

Comment: Good clarification with your 'Edit to expand'. The order in the stylesheet mattering is a bit insidious...

Comment: I did not realize the order in the stylesheet mattered like this!

Answer (score 17):

Just wanted to throw out another option in addition to !important as well as style definition order: you can chain the two together as well:

```
.myclass.myclass-right{float:right;}
.myclass{float:left;}
```

Answer (score 16):

Using `!important` is one way to do it.

```
.myclass-right{
    float:right !important;
}
```

In addition if you are more specific with your selector it should override as well

```
div.myclass-right{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As long as `myclass-right` is declared *after* your other class in your css file, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

In case of a conflict, the css tag that comes **after** has a priority.

In other words - if you want some class to ever override others - just put it on end of your css file.

P.S. But don't forget that more specific rules has more priority, like `.a.b {}` is more powerful than just `.a{}`