# Can the Class attribute contain more than 1 css class?

Tags: html, css

So If I'm working on designing a page for a website, can I give the class attribute *multiple css classes*? For example, is this correct and will it display all the css code located in these classes? Thanks!

---

```
<a class="account-group js-account-group js-action-profile js-user-profile-link"></a>
```

Comment: Why is someone so sad to downvote a question haha seriously, whats wrong with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple classes in html like you're having just by separating different classes with space.

Look at the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and well know answer: Yes

Comment: Thanks @Bharadwaj. The missing quote was from editing the text on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's completely valid.

However the rules will override each other in corresponding order.

For example, if account-group and js-account-group both have a rule of, let's say, font-size, it'll take the value of js-account-group if that makes sense

I'm on my phone so it's hard to explain properly and add formatting

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and what you wrote is right.
But be careful the override issue
[css-multiple-classes-property-override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127337/css-multiple-classes-property-override)