# Ember 1.13, class names order in a component

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js

I've created a simple component to render icons from SVG sprite. This component should have a default CSS class to manage it's styles globally (.svg-icon). Also, I want to have a possibility to add some context dependent styles via class names through 'class' attribute.

JS:

```
App.SvgIconComponent = Ember.Component.extend
   layoutName: 'components/svg-icon'
   classNames: ['svg-icon']
   tagName: 'svg'
   attributeBindings: ['width', 'height', 'fill'],

   width: 16
   height: 16
   fill: 'currentColor'
```

Template:

```
<use xlink:href="#svg-icon-{{name}}"/>
```

Usage:

```
{{svg-icon name="facebook" class="social__icon" width="14" height="14"}}
```

HTML output:

```
<svg id="ember1012" width="14" height="14" fill="currentColor" class="social__icon ember-view svg-icon">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-icon-facebook"></use>
</svg>
```

The problem is that Ember pushed my default class (.svg-icon) into the end of classes list. But, to avoid some issues with cascade, I need this class at the start of classes list (class="svg-icon social__icon ember-view"). Is it possible to achieve?

I know, that I can set classes names with classNameBindings property, but in this case I will need to use some attribute different from 'class'. Use of native 'class' attribute is preferable.

Thnx.

Comment: Does the order classes are defined in the classList matter in SVG? It [doesn't on other HTML elements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8127373/557612).

Comment: @steveax Ha, I was sure that it's matter but it doesn't! So my question has no more sense. Thnx for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
{{svg-icon name="facebook" classNames="social__icon" width="14" height="14"}}
```

The above will work but it is not using class attribute. so its not matching your requirement.

but if that does not align with your requirement, you can try setting classNames manually in `init` method.

```
init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    console.log(' Classess ',this.get('classNames')); //You will get classNames, you can do rearrange the classNames array
    this.get('classNames').unshiftObject('svg-icon'); //to force svg-icon to be first in classNames array.    
  }
```

**Update1**

Above init() won't work. so I believe `classNames` values are added to last. using native `class` to come first is not possible AFAIK. but then for your requirement

> I know, that I can set classes names with classNameBindings property, but in this case I will need to use some attribute different from 'class'

You can mention different class names for particular attribute is true.

```
{{my-component is_social__icon=false }}
```

and inside `my-component.js`

```
classNameBindings:['is_social__icon:social__icon']
```

**Update2**
1)You can also specify class names for true and false values too in classNameBindings

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['isEnabled:enabled:disabled'],
  isEnabled: false
});
```

`isEnabled` - true - then it will include `enabled` class name
`isEnabled` - false - then it will include `disabled` class name

2) You can even specify class name to be added only for false value.

```
 classNameBindings: ['isEnabled::disabled'],
```

3) you can specify multiple properties

```
 classNameBindings:['isSocialIcon':'social__icon','isActive':'selected']
```

you can provide values for `isSocialIcon` and `isActive` property to the component.

```
{{my-component isSocialIcon=true isActive=(unless social.inactive) }}
```

if `isActive` is resolved to true then it will add class `social__icon selected` to my-component.

Reference : https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-class-names

Comment: Solution with init hook don't work, this.get('classNames') returns an array of classes without classes added in template, it contain only 'ember-view' class... And resulting HTML is: class="my_custom_class_from view svg-icon ember-view".

Comment: Thanks for update, but I want to avoid using extra attributes especially with booleans values, it makes component more complex and difficult for reuse. The main idea was to keep only attributes like on original SVG tag (width, height, fill and class), designers and HTML guys feels more comfortable with known attributes than with custom.

Comment: It's possible to save classes order if use classNames attribute, but I've also faced with a problem when I need add a class name dynamically:
class=(concat 'social__icon ' (unless social.inactive 'selected')) - working good, but: classNames=(concat 'social__icon ' (unless social.inactive 'selected')) doesn't work

Comment: To include component `{{my-component inactive=social.inactive }}`  and inside component.js - `classNameBindings:['inactive:social__iconselected:social__icon'],`  there are lot more choices available in classNameBindings..[reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-class-names).