# Order of the css classes on an element matters?

Tags: html, css

Order of the class names that are added using *class* attribute on a HTML element matters?

Say I have two elements like:

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
<div class="class2 class1"></div>
```

And we have classes defined like:

```
.class1 {
   color:#fff;
   ....
}
.class2{
   color:#333;
   ....
}
```

What is the effect of the classes order here? Which color wins for both divs? Thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked before, see it here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066356/multiple-css-classes-properties-overlapping-based-on-the-order-defined

Answer (score 2):

Only the order of the rules in the CSS matters.

In your case CSS works like this:

1. Apply `color:#fff;` to all `.class1` elements
2. Then: apply `color:#333;` to all `.class2` elements

So both `div`s will have `color:#333;`.