# How to move global styles into a scope for emotion?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

I'm currently need to integrate common components of a library into multiples websites. The component Library currently have a Global styles. That they inject in the following way:

```js
  <Global
    styles={`
        div {
          padding: 0;
        }
    `}
  />
```

I want there "Global styles" only available for the components of this library. They are only on a part of the page.

So I've try this:

```js
const Styles = styled.div`
        div {
          padding: 0;
        }
`;

const Page = () => (
    <Styles>
        <SomeComponentsOfTheLibrary />
    </Styles>
);
```

But it seems that everything in `Styles` has the priority. Then if the component has `padding: 10px;` it will take `padding: 0;` of `Styles`

Here is the issue reproduced:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-glitter-g3gbd

I know it's a css issue but I want to solve it with emotion

I've already saw:

- https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1264
- https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1386
- https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/760

Comment: I know it relys on the order of creation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066356/multiple-css-classes-properties-overlapping-based-on-the-order-defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to move global styles into a scope for emotion ?

[@Andarist](https://github.com/Andarist) found a solution for that by creating a [stylis plugin for extra scope](https://github.com/Andarist/stylis-plugin-extra-scope)

### Example

#### Create a cache with stylis plugin for extra scope

```js
const STRONG_ID = 'very-strong-id';
const cache = createCache({
  stylisPlugins: [createExtraScopePlugin(`#${STRONG_ID}`)],
});
```

#### Use your global styles in the cache provider

```js
     <CacheProvider value={cache}>
        <Global
          styles={css`
            div {
              background-color: red;
            }
          `}
        />
        <div id={STRONG_ID}>
          <div>I must be red (global style scoped to the parent div)</div>
          <Container>
            I must be blue (local style defined on this div)
          </Container>
        </div>
      </CacheProvider>
```

Then your global styles will be scope by `very-strong-id`

You can find the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-morning-8rfur)

Hope it will help someone in the future

Comment: Note this does not work for emotion v11

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with CacheProvider which works with emotion is

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";

const STRONG_ID = "unique-strong-id";

const cache = createCache({
  key: STRONG_ID
});

export default function Home() {
  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#333",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#eee",
      },
    },
  });

  return <CacheProvider value={cache}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        Hello
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </CacheProvider>
}
```