# merge attributes - how do I get them to function properly?

Tags: laravel, components

i have the following in a component stored in resources/views/components/green-button.blade.php in laravel 8.

```
<button {{ $attributes->merge(['type' => 'button', 'class' => 'px-4 inline-flex justify-center py-2 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500']) }}>
    {{ $slot }}
</button>
```

I use it :

```
<x-green-button class="px-0"
                title="Click to show or hide data entry for {{$person->firstname}}."
                wire:click="toggleVisibility({{$person->id}})">
  <h3 class="my-1">{{$person->FullName_fh}}</h3>
</x-green-button>
```

The component has an x axis padding of px-4.  I pass px-0, but there is no effect.  What am I doing wrong?

rbd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@props()` to achieve the goal.

```
// In your component

@props(['customClass' => ''])

<button {{ $attributes->merge([
    'type'  => 'button', 
    'class' => 'all-your-classes ' . $customClass
]) }}>
    {{ $slot }}
</button>
```

```
// In your blade file

<x-green-button customClass="px-0">
    {{ $person->FullName_fh }}
</x-green-button>
```

Comment: hi, thx.  if the 'all-your-classes' has 'px-4' in it, and $customClass = 'px-0', will the px-4 take precedence because it comes first?, or does the last contradicting class take precedence?  Thx S.

Comment: @RobertBryanDavis It depends on the stylesheet order, See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3066365/13916713

Comment: Hi,  thx for the feedback.  I gained the funcctionality i was seeking by using props() and passing in adjustments to styles that way.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve the functionality as @Samuel Ferdary explained.

But I found this article useful: [Override class attributes in Blade component](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/override-class-attributes-in-blade-component)

Summary:

As of Tailwind CSS 3+, you can override existing class selectors by prepending the important operator:

```html
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'bg-red-500']) }}> 
  {{ $slot }}
</div>

<x-component class="text-gray-700 !bg-blue-500">
  {{ $slot }}
</x-component>
```